# Docker open outside ports - not opening the good ones

Tags: docker, port, iptables

I am running a rabbitmq docker instance, which uses the 5671 port.

```
docker run -p 65000:5671 rabbitmq
```

If I then do `iptables -L -v` while running the instance, I get the following DOCKER chain:

```
target     prot opt in       out      source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  !docker0 docker0  anywhere             xxx  tcp dpt:5671
```

It seems to me that docker is doing exactly what's wrong, ie. it should modify iptables to allow connections on 65000 instead of 5671.

Am I getting something wrong here?

NB: I want to be able to fire different instances of rabbitmq on the same machine, so:

- I need the "outer" port (here `65000`) to be "variable"
- I would like to be able to decide at `docker run`-time which port to use (and thus, which port to open)

Comment: As a thanks for the -1 and the close suggestion, I suggest you go check the near-0 level of activity that my question received on ServerFault: http://serverfault.com/questions/671870/docker-open-ports-in-iptables-rabbitmq ;)

Comment: Yeah, someone seems to be voting to close all docker questions. It's not very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You've just got the syntax back to front, it's `-p HOST_PORT:CONTAINER_PORT`, which will forward requests from `HOST_PORT` on the host to `CONTAINER_PORT` on the container.

If you just specify a single port, it will be assumed to be the container port and will assigned to a random high numbered port on the host, so I think `-p 5671` will do what you want.

Alternatively, if you've used an `EXPOSE` statement in your Dockerfile, you can use the `-P` flag with no arguments to automatically assign free high numbered ports to the exposed ports on the container.

Note that the `docker port` command will give the port mappings for a container.

Comment: Got it backwards indeed! Guess the docs were not so clear for my mind, especially knowing that I'm also using `-p 127.0.0.1::5672` which was pretty confusing me: here the localhost-available port is written at the end of the argument after the 2nd `:`

Comment: Yeah, to be honest I had to double check myself. Most things are host first in Docker; volumes work the same way.

Comment: Actually I think we're both missing the point: your suggestion is wrong as mentioned from someone on freenode #docker. I was having it in the good sense, and I have indeed to manipulate my iptables by hand. Docker doesn't do the job for the external mapping

Comment: @lajarre: you mean you want to expose ports on the host to the outside world? That's nothing to do with Docker, but it's also not what you asked...

Comment: So finally we both got the syntax in the good way, the whole story is that it's my business to figure out how to make my docker instances ports open to the outside and so on...